# Filtering SQL Server sys.objects by database

Tags: sql-server, database, metadata

Should be easy, but I can't get it.

I want to filter the sys.objects results by database (either name or id). I thought I had to join with sys.databases, but does not seem to be possible. I went to SQL Servers docs but did not find anything that could help.

What am I missing?

Comment: You always only see database objects from the **current** database anyway - so why do you need to filter by database?? Doesn't really make sense to me...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each Database have its own sys.objects, so you have to get the databases from sys.databases, and

```
select from {dbname}.sys.objects
```

{dbname} is the `name` from sys.databases

Comment: Also: I would recommend to use the more focused views like `sys.tables`, `sys.procedures` etc. instead of just `sys.objects` - saves you to have to specify an object type (since that's clear from the focused views already)

Comment: Ok, I was mislead by objects like 'sysrowsetcolumns, 'sysowners'. They appear in sys.objects but not in Management Studio "System Tables" node nor in sys.tables, so I thought they came from other databases. It turns out they are - some how - part of my db.